# Java: What's the reason to write Supertype a = new Subtyp()`?

Tags: java, oop

Assume that class B extends from class A.

So what is the advantage of writing something like this:

```
A myClassA = new B();
```

What's the difference to:

```
B myClassA = new B();
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: To decouple a client class using the interface (or the superclass contract) from the spercific implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the concept of programming to interfaces(or supertype)
we use supertype reference so that it can hold any sub type instance

eg: assume we have Class B & C extending A

& some method which accepts  A as parameter

void print(A a) {System.out.println(a);}

this method canbe invoked by passing any instance of A or its subtype

Answer (score 3):

Because then if `C` is a subtype of `A`, you can say

```
myClassA = new C();
```

and your code would (should) still work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

That you may assign an instance of `A` to `myClassA` later.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that if B extends A but all exposed API is defined in A you can treat the object as A without knowing its real type. If future you will probably add yet another implementation C that extends A as well and will probably start using C and B together but you will not have to change the code that uses these objects because it treats them as A.

Answer (score 1):

`Program to interface, not an implemenation`. 
For example,

```
A myClassA = new B();
```

Here you can change the implementation, `new C()` without affecting the existing code since you just exposed the interface.

```
A myClassA = new C();
```

or

```
A myClassA = getClassATypeInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example is the Collections API.

Look at the static "min" method of java.util.Collections.
The Parameter type is "Collection" and a lot of classes implement this interface.
You may get the min from a ArrayList (implements List extends Collection) or the values of a HashMap (HashMap.values() returns a private implementation of the Collection interface).

If the java.util.Collections.min() has a ArrayList as parameter type you couldn't use the method to get the minimum value of a HashMap.

Declare your variables and parameters with the basetype if you don't need the additional methods you get through the Subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

A good example is always that of shapes. Let's say we have two shapes, a circle and a square. Both have different properties, but we can get the area of both.

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract float area();
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    private float radius;

    public Circle(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public float area() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    private float width;
    private float height;

    public Square (float width, float height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height= height;
    }

    @Override
    public float area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

Now what this implementation allows, is to calculate the area of all shapes regardless of what types they are. You can for instance have an array of Shapes and iterate over them, calling the area function of each shape and summing the areas up.

One should always put the right information in the right class. Circles and squares both have areas, and so does other shapes to, so it is safe to assume that area is a property of a shape, i.e. circle's have an area because they are shapes.

Putting it lower in the class hierarchy gives your code a healthy level of abstraction. It becomes sort of a "need-to-know-basis"-principle, where you should never have access to more code that you need at the moment. Another rule of thumb is to code so that you always cast from subtype to base, and never the other way around (which is a lot harder than it sounds).